# How can i change the path to allow it not to be hard coded

Tags: java, path

I want to change the path so that anyone can access the sound and image files on their pc and so that it isn't restricted to this specific path. I've tried using

```
linky.add(new ChampsC(values[i], new File("..\\Resources\\Sounds\\" + values[i] + ".wav"),
                new File("..\\Resources\\Images\\" + values[i] + ".jpg")));
```

with no success

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
    {
        // Auto making all the objects

        linky.add(new ChampsC(values[i], new File("C:\\Users\\Spider\\Desktop\\LeageSoundGame\\src\\Resources\\Sounds\\" + values[i] + ".wav"),
            new File("C:\\Users\\Spider\\Desktop\\LeageSoundGame\\src\\Resources\\Images\\" + values[i] + ".jpg")));
    }
```

Comment: String basePath=args[0]; linky.add(new ChampsC(values[i], new File(basePath + "/" + values[i] + ".wav"),
                    new File("basePath + "/" + values[i] + ".jpg")));  Here args is the string array being asked from User or you can set this file path from someproperty file

Comment: i dont understand what this does please can you explain